# Why does this loop return 1 when using && instead of 'and'?

Tags: logic, php, gearman

Riddle me this... in the `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) and $runningOK)` loop, if the PHP `&&` operator is used in place of the `and` then `mysql_fetch_assoc` fails terribly and returns just the number `1` when running.

I've tried `mysql_fetch_array()` and in place and I still have the `1` problem. It is when, and only when, I replace the `&&` with an `and` like the current `while` statement that the correct rows are returned.

I had placed debug statements before, inside, and after to insure this. I would like to know if this is a PHP quirk or something I couldn't account for.

```
// Query
$selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM jobs_cache LIMIT 20";
// Run the Selection Query.
$result = mysql_query($selectQuery)
    or die('Query Failed: '.mysql_error());

// Loop through results.
$runningOK = TRUE;
$resubmitList = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) and $runningOK)
{
    // Resubmit The Job
    try
    {
        $client->addTaskBackground($row['function_name'],$row['job_data']);
        $resubmitList[] = (string)$row['job_cache_id'];
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo "Error adding task for job id: " . $row['job_cache_id'];
        $runningOK = FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's due to operator precedence. See [the manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) for details... here's the relevant part.

> // "&&" has a greater precedence than
> "and"
>
> // The result of the expression (true && false) is assigned to $g
> // Acts like: ($g = (true && false))
>
> $g = true && false;
>
> // The constant true is assigned to $h and then false is ignored
> // Acts like: (($h = true) and false)
>
> $h = true and false;
>
> var_dump($g, $h);
>
> bool(false)
> bool(true)

So, with the &&, the result of the expression is assigned to true, which evaluates to 1. With and, it evaluates to the result of the mysql function - more what you want, I reckon.

By the way, you could also use `break` to eliminate the need for the $runningOK variable. To do so, remove  `and $runningOK` from the `while` condition and change `$runningOK = FALSE;` to `break;` and it will end the loop if the catch block is triggered.

Comment: this is a snipet out of a much larger Gearman Worker Kernel, the running ok is used in a few sections to insure we have valid SQL calls and worker health. What a wonderful and clear explanation of the precedence!

Comment: Also grats on the 1000 rep :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) and $runningOK)
```

There might be a mix up, as it is evaluating `mysql_fetch_assoc($result) and $runningOK` to TRUE, which it then assigns to `$row`, which in this case is the same as `1`

If you add the parenthesis, you most likely can use either `&&` or `and`, as you will have properly separated the two evaluations.

This is the side effect of alternative syntaxes I'm sure.

Comment: My money's on this explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment operator `=` and the two logical operators `&&` and `AND` have [different precedence](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php): `&&` is executed before `=`, which in turn is executed before `AND`

So basically the statement:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) AND $runningOK
```

is equal to:

```
($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) AND $runningOK
```

while the statement:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) && $runningOK
```

is equal to:

```
$row = (mysql_fetch_assoc($result) && $runningOK)
```

In the last case you are just assigning values 1 (if mysql_fetch_assoc returns a value) or 0.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the operator resolving prescedence.

Check out this table to understand:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Use () as much as you need when you don't know how it's resolved.